# What kinds of routes does Yii2 rest\UrlRule generate from a multi-word controller name?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I guess i should apologize for such a dumb question, but what URL will Yii2 generate for, let's say, BigLongControllerNameController.php?

I guess, it should be /big-long-controller-name/ ?

Doesn't work in my case, i am getting 404

I also tried biglongcontrollername, big_long_controller_name, bigLongControllerName, either in browser and config. Documentation doesn't help, either i am blind or REST routing rules are obvious for everyone enough not to specify them in Yii2 docs

My current routing rules

```
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' =>
                    [
                        'group',
                        'course',
                        'user',
                        'teacher',
                        'holiday',
                        'pupil',
                        'additional',
                        'degree',
//                        'big-long-controller-name',
//                        'BigLongControllerName',
//                        'bigLongControllerName',
//                        'big_long_controller_name',
                    ]
                ],
                '/' => 'site/index',
                '/auth' => 'site/auth',
            ],
        ],
```

Controller doesn't have anything special in it. It works just fine when I rename it to AdditionalController.php

```
class BigLongControllerNameController extends RESTController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\AdditionalFieldOption';

    public function behaviors()
    {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['access']['except'] = ['view', 'index', 'options'];
        $behaviors['access']['rules'] =
        [
            [
                'actions' => ['view', 'index', 'options', 'update', 'delete', 'create'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['admin'],
            ],
        ];
        return $behaviors;
    }
```

Should i post the whole config?

Comment: `Controller` is a keyword you are using it twice in `BigLongControllerNameController ` whereas it needs to be at the end of the controller name

Comment: Other names do not work either, i started with AdditionalFieldOptionController

Comment: are you using a separate app for API or a simple rest controllers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By default, controller IDs should contain these characters only: English letters in lower case, digits, underscores, hyphens, and forward slashes. For example, article and post-comment are both valid controller IDs, while article?, PostComment, admin\post are not.

See this [link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-controllers#controller-ids).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the answer is:

For a controller class named BigLongNameController Yii2's rest\UrlRule would generate URL /big-long-controller-name**s**/ and NOT /big-long-controller-name/ because it has a feature called pluralization, which is enabled by default. I somehow forgot about that. Sorry again for a stupid question.

In case someone comes there from Google, the correct config looks something like this:

```
            'rules' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' =>
                    [
                        'group',
                        'course',
                        'user',
                        'teacher',
                        'holiday',
                        'pupil',
                        'additional',
                        'degree',
                        'big-long-controller-name',
                    ]
```

The controller class and his file must be named with camelcase, and not hyphens, e.g. BigLongControllerNameController.php containing:

```
class BigLongControllerNameController extends ActiveController {
 // your code
}
```

The URL would be /big-long-controller-names

Comment: Thankful. It is also an important question and tip.